# Branch & Mixpanel integration legacy data

Tags: branch.io, mixpanel

On our android/iOS app we use Branch and Mixpanel and a while ago we integrated the two following this document: https://docs.branch.io/integrations/mixpanel/

Few weeks ago we realized that the INSTALLs  events from iOS are propagated correctly to Mixpanel. While from Android we can see the INSTALLs on Branch but don't see them propagated to Mixpanel.

So I thought that the issue is the propagation from Branch to Mixpanel and 
when accessing on Branch "Data Import & Export -> Data Feeds -> Data Integration"  I see the following warning:

> You have legacy Webhooks or Data Integrations enabled. | Give feedback.Learn more. | View Legacy
>   [image: legacy data]

When tapping on "View Legacy" the page reload but I'm presented the page with the same content and warning.

Any way to see my legacy data? 
Or maybe something else I should check to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

can you submit a ticket [here](https://support.branch.io/support/tickets/new/) with the Branch App ID in question and screenshot of the error that you get on the dashboard. We can take it from there.

Comment: I did, twice, and after 3 days no answer. And I don't get any error on the dashboard.